# Both for & each loops stop after first match when iterating through a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement, hash, return

I'm trying to print out the values of a hash where their corresponding keys match a certain condition (if they're odd).

I'm having an issue that's causing my loop to stop working after

The following code returns only the first matching value.

```
if mycondition
 for key,value in myhash do
   if key.odd?
     return "#{value}"
   end
 end
end
```

After reading some other questions, I thought `return` was my issue, but when I take it out, the code returns the entire hash instead of just one matching value.

Anyone know what might be up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much more Ruby way of doing it:

```
myhash.select do |key, value|
  key.odd?
end.values
```

Here it finds all the odd keys and returns the associated values.

The problem with your `return` is that forces the whole method to exit right then and there. If you're used to JavaScript that might be a little confusing, as you're not just exiting the `do` block.

As a note the `for` construct is hardly ever used in Ruby. A more conventional way of expressing your original code is:

```
myhash.each do |key, value|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you `return`, the function is over, so that's why you get only one key.

If you don't `return` anything, the function returns its final expression, which in this case is the `for` loop. `for` loops evaluate to the thing you looped over (`myhash`), so that's why removing the `return` gives you everything.

In your case you need to build up the list of things you want to return, and that return that whole list:

```
if mycondition
  ret = []
  for key, value in myhash do
    if key.odd?
      ret << [key, value]
    end
  end
  return Hash[ret]
end
```

But Ruby has much nicer ways to pull out a subset of a hash, for example:

```
Hash[myhash.select{|k,v| k.odd?}]
```

Comment: Even better than your last example: [`Hash#reject`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject)